# Use ORDER BY UNIX_DATE() for join table in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In my queries, I have used the *unix_date* function to group and count the data from backlogs to specific date. All works very well.

```
..
     
    SELECT  
      *,
    FROM 
      table1 
    FULL OUTER JOIN table2 USING (ID)
```

I'm not sure what should I add for the joining part to get a right query. I skipped the details of query as the query is quite long to be put on this post. Please let me know if you need the full query.

Problem: I think the join table append the row instead of just adding the column from joined query results because there are many same IDs in all tables (many-many relationship problem).However, not sure how to solve it.

Comment: you may want to evaluate the join type you used. try left join?

Comment: did it. same problem occurs. I think this is because the many-many relationship join. I have many of same ID in each query.. but not sure how I can fix it, as i though JOIN table will just append the column, instead duplicate rows

Comment: Can you share tables you want to join? And expected result.. so that easier for other people to detect the problem

Comment: edited with the sample input/output and footnote

Comment: @nick . . . No, you haven't shown the original data.  You seem to have shown the results of your CTEs.  I would suggest that you set up a db/sql fiddle with relevant data and the tables you are really using.

Comment: check [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks..updated question with original data

Answer (score 2):

Solved using composite key.

```
..

    SELECT  
      *,
    FROM 
      table1 
    FULL OUTER JOIN table2 USING (ID, Date)
```